# Method not executed inside lambda callback of MessageCenter xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I a using the MessageCenter class in order to pass a string from Android native code to Xamarin Shared code.But I face the following issue. On the bellow code I am sending the string and they i can receive it but from the expressions inside the Action delegate only the debug statement is executed the other are simply ignored.

```
         public partial class Search : ContentPage
{



    public Search()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

       }






        MessagingCenter.Send<string>("xamarin", "FromAndroid");

        //receing msg from android shared intent between apps
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<string>(this, "FromAndroid", (msg) =>
       {

           searchBar.Text = msg;   // that line do not update my UI search text if is outside is 
        updated
           Debug.WriteLine("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ " + msg);




       });


    }











}
```

Normally the Send method is located in the Android Project I just move it here for brevity. I can confirm that the  Subscribe method successfully receive the "xamarin" string .

Comment: UI updates can only happen on the main thread.  Try using BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Comment: do u mean something like this Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { searchBar.Text = msg; }); but it was not working also I ques now the Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread is also in separate tread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and code, I suggest you can try to subscribe to a message firstly, then send to message.

From your code, you just send message, then subscribe a message, so you can not update UI.

I use the code in ContentPage constructor, it still can change UI.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="label1" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>

 public  Page16()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page16, string>(this, "Xamarin", async (sender, arg) =>
        {
            label1.Text = arg;
        });
        MessagingCenter.Send<Page16, string>(this,"Xamarin","this is test");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass a parameter you need two type arguments

```
MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "FromAndroid", "data");

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, string>(this, "FromAndroid", async (sender, arg) =>
{
    searchBar.Text = arg; 
}
```

Comment: The parameter which i want to pass is received from the subscriber the  problem is the is not updating the UI.  I tried with  DisplayAlert(); same story .

Comment: What parameter?  The code you posted does not include any parameters in your Send() call

Comment: I have entirely remove my code and replace it with yours but still searchBar.Text is not affected.

Comment: you may also need to use InvokeOnMainThread.  Are you **positive** that the value in `arg` is getting received by `Subscribe`?

Comment: Yes Debug.WriteLine always is executed and the values is correct.I also just now tried to change the UI control with simple button to try to change the text but fail.

Comment: then there is something else wrong that you are now showing

Comment: What I found is that MessageCenter need to be inside a UI control in order to work . If is fired from other places it will not work.